# What does this regex do?

Tags: php, regex

We learn everyday. I came across this script and though i am new to regex would like to know if it's a safe script to use and what it does actually.

From I assume it removes clickable links in an a text but would ilke to know more.

```
function new_regex($text = '')
{
    $text = preg_replace('#(script|about|applet|activex|chrome):#is', "\\1:", $text);
    $ret = ' ' . $text;
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);

    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)#i", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $ret);
    $ret = substr($ret, 1);
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: This type of question must not be asked here in stackoverflow rather it should be asked in codereview section . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line does surprisingly little. It looks for active scripting uri prefixes, but replaces them with themselves. That seems a misguided attempt at security something.

The three following preg_replace calls replace `http://` URLs or just `www.*` domain names and `xyz@email` addresses. But it does not remove them, it replaces them with clickable HTML links.

Comment: HTML links to where or of what?

Comment: You pass this function source text with a literal `... www.google.com ...` somewhere within. And this function replaces it with [`.. www.google.com ..`](http://www.google.com). It's a 1:1 replacement, it does not generate different urls/links.

Comment: Actually the first one removes a trailing colon `:` from any `script:`, `about:`, `applet:`, `activex:` or `chrome:` URLs. Thus, these are effectively hidden from the processing statements which follow.

Comment: @ridgerunner: That's what I thought, but the replacement string is `"\1:"` meaning it adds the `:` back on. I've run it through, it has no effect. But that's still the most plausible explanation on what it was intended for.